# Exhaustive character replacement of up to n length

Tags: python

I am fairly adept at Python, however this problem is really racking my mind and I need help.

Given the following:

```
alphabet_string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
letters = [x for x in alphabet_string]
max_replacements = 3
```

I'd like to find all possible replacements up to `max_replacements`.

So for example, the first iteration would add this to a list:

```
AACDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Where the `B` is replaced by `A` - given the fact that it's the first element in the `letters` list. The second iteration would then do this:

```
ABADEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

And so on and so on. After one complete iteration over `letters` has been completed through the `alphabet_string` then the replacement will begin like:

```
AAADEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

And then:

```
ABAAEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

And so on.

It's probably really simplistic, but I'm lost. Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: It's not clear how these replacements are supposed to work. Please provide a more precise problem statement.

Comment: Do you want to replace always with an A? Or would a string like `ZBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` be good as well?

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi, Yes. :)

Comment: Yes to which of the two questions?

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi, I'd like it to iterate through all of the letters list, so ```ZBCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ``` is also an expected output.

Comment: There are `25*26 + (25**2 * (26 choose 2)) + ((25**3 * (26 choose 3)) = 40 828 775` different strings available, if I did the calculation correctly. Are you sure you want them all?

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I do it recursively. I obtain the correct number of items in the output and I manually checked it for simpler problems. Thanks for asking the question, it was real fun!

```
alphabet_string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
max_replacements = 3

def find_neighbours(word, alphabet, n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("negative n!")
    if n == 0:
        return [word]
    out = []
    for l in alphabet:
        k = n if l == word[0] else n-1
        res = find_neighbours(word[1:], alphabet, k)
        out += [l + r for r in res]
    return out    

out = find_neighbours(alphabet_string, alphabet_string, max_replacements)
```